# Ubuntu purple splash screen with blinking pixels?

Tags: linux, boot, ubuntu-10.04, splash

I had ubuntu 9.10 
I upgraded to 10.04 after solving some problems (freeze at boot).

Since then, I don't have the ubuntu's logo  showing up when I boot, but a purple screen with some blinking pixels. I didn't care much about it... but today my computer took too long at that screen (normally it was just 1/4 second, but today it was like a minute..). And it happened like 4 or 5 times in a row (Only at the 5th time I realised that it was not freezing up, but it simply would took more time)

After a reboot, it is again 1/4 second of purple screen but I don't want this problem to return.. so I want to get rid of the purple screen (I think it is an indicator of the problem)

Well, I already installed the graphic drivers (going to system > admnistration > hardware drivers). But it didn't solve anything. (I don't know if it is even related)

I searched in google, found something old (2006) and I think it maybe has some relation with my problems ..
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-294692.html

But couldn't understand the conversation (i'm a linux novice)

Sorry for my horrible english..
I would appreciate any help!

My hardware: 
ATI Mobility Radeon 4650 HD
P7450 2.13Ghz Core 2 Duo

Comment: You do know 10.04 is still in beta, don't you?

Comment: Yes. But does that implicate that the problem can't be solved in anyway but waiting for the final release?

Comment: Hmmm, your English actually seems pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

10,04 is switching to a new slash screen system - so the problem may be related to that. I suggest reporting a bug against the Beta - include your full system specs, and both problems.

Also make sure you have applied all updates - and all the Beta2 updates next week.

Finally you can remove the slash screen - from the boot configuration.